# Graph not displayed while plotting 3D graph using vis.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, vis.js

I have started using vis.js javascript library. I came some problem while plotting using the following code:

```
var mydataset = new vis.DataSet();
var counter =0;
var steps = 50;  // number of datapoints will be steps*steps
var thetaStep = 180/steps;
var phiStep = 360/steps;
for (var mytheta = -90; mytheta <= 90; mytheta+=thetaStep)
{
    for (var myphi = 0; myphi<=360; myphi+=phiStep) 
    {
        var xcord = (Math.asin(Math.sin(mytheta*(Math.PI/180))*Math.cos(myphi*(Math.PI/180))))*(180/Math.PI);
        var ycord = (Math.asin(Math.sin(mytheta*(Math.PI/180))*Math.sin(myphi*(Math.PI/180))))*(180/Math.PI);
        var fvalue = Some_random_function(mytheta,myphi);
        var zcord = 20*Math.log10(fvalue);
        var style = zcord;
        mydataset.add({id:counter++,x:xcord,y:ycord,z:zcord,style:style}); 
    }
}

var options = {
    width:  '1200px',
    height: '1000px',
    style: 'surface',
    showPerspective: true,
    showGrid: true,
    showShadow: false,
    keepAspectRatio: true,
    verticalRatio: 0.5,
    tooltip:function(point){
        return 'value: <b>'+point.z+'</b>';
    }
};

var container = document.getElementById('graph');
var graph3d = new vis.Graph3d(container, mydataset, options);
```

I get no graph/chart displayed. But when I hover the mouse on the canvas region I get the tooltip indication as normally. Where did I go wrong.. No Graph but still tool tip is displayed. Need to change any options..??

But when I plotted the graph using the below following code (by changing the xcord and ycord assignments)

```
var xcord = mytheta; //line #10
var ycord = myphi; //line #11
```

There is some graph and nice tooltip indication.

Is there anywhere I am going wrong.. Please help.. Thanks in advance

Is there anyother javascript library where I can plot Nice Interactive ( panning and zooming ) 3D graphs.

Comment: When I changed the style options from 'surface' to 'line', I observe the desired plot. Why is the plot observed for 'line' and not for 'surface'..??

Comment: Show definition of the `Some_random_function`.